NextJS Web App Sending Message to React/Vite Chrome Extension
I am having difficulty figuring out how to receive data in my React/Vite Chrome extension  from my NextJS webapp. In the webapp, users create a set of data which I want to display in the extension. I am able to successfully send the data from the webapp to the extension service-worker and view it in the console log. What I am struggling with is how to send that data from the service-worker to my extension to be able to store the data in the extension local storage and then display the data in the extension side panel. So far, I have the following in my service-worker.js file:
chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(
  (request, sender, sendResponse) => {
    const data = JSON.parse(request);
    if (data.name) {
      (async () => {
        if (data.type === "open_side_panel") {
          await chrome.sidePanel.open({
            tabId: sender.tab.id,
          });
          await chrome.tabs.sendMessage(sender.tab.id, data);
        }
      })();
      console.log(data);
      sendResponse({ success: true, message: "Data has been received" });
    }
  }
);

As I mentioned, I am able to see data in the console log but what I need help with is receiving the data in the React/Vite app which opens in the extension side panel. My understanding is that I can't set local storage from within the service-worker so I am sending the data as a message (already in the service-worker code above) but how do I listen for that message within the React/Vite app in order to process the data and set it to local storage?
TIA

Your side panel probably adds its onMessage listener too late (e.g. asynchronously inside the react app). You can also use chrome.storage.local or chrome.storage.session.
